# Use of 'where' and 'or' together in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue about use of `where` and `or` together.

```
Item.where(a: true) 
.where("b>=?", 1) 
.or(Item.where(c: true)) 
.where(d: true)
```

What I am trying to achieve is, after the first condition which is `a: true`, find if any Items are `b >=?, 1`. if any items found, move to the fourth condition which is `where(d:true)` but if nothing found, move to the third condition which is `or(Item.where(c: true)` and if some items are found from the third condition, move to the fourth condition`.where(d:true)`.

This is what I am trying to achieve but it seems like when the `items` reached to the third condition `.or(Item.where(c: true))`, it didn't pass the previous conditions.

I added the previous conditions inside of the third condition such as `or(Item.where(a:true).where("b>=?",1).where(c:true))` but is there any better way to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

"if" and "move to" are not very clear ways to look at an SQL expression... it's generally best to think of it as all being evaluated at once, unlike in an imperative language.

However, I think this is the query you want:

```
a_items = Item.where(a: true)
a_items.where("b >= ?", 1).
  or(a_items.where(c: true)).
  where(d: true)
```

It's basically the same "repeat the conditions inside the `or`" approach it sounds like you're already using, but instead of actually repeating them, we use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic boils down to this:

```
a IS TRUE 
AND (b >= 1 OR c IS TRUE)
AND d IS TRUE
```

This can be expressed as:

```
Item
  .where(a: true) 
  .merge(
    Item
      .where("b>=?", 1) 
      .or(Item.where(c: true)) 
  )
  .where(d: true)
```